# MySqlConnection ExecuteNonQuery UPDATE error

Tags: mysql

After changing from OleDB to MySqlConnect I'm having an issue with the ExecuteNonQuery throwing an error in UPDATE sql - existing code worked fine updating the access DB with committed out OleDB lines :

```
Public Function InsertClassRecord(ByVal UserName As String, ByVal Instructor As String, _
                                  ByVal DateCompleted As Date, ByVal Completed As Boolean, _
                                  ByVal Enrolled As Boolean, ByVal ClassName As String, _
                                  ByVal ClassDate As Date, ByVal WaitListed As Boolean, _
                                  ByVal Walkin As Boolean) As Object

    Dim connStr As String = "Datasource=localhost;Database=MYSQL_Training;uid=username;pwd=password;"

    'Dim conn As New Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connStr)
    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection(connStr)

    conn.ConnectionString = connStr
    conn.Open()

    Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO EnrollmentsTbl (" & _
    "[UserName],[SubmitTime],[ClassTime],[ClassDate],[Enrolled],[ClassName],[WaitListed]," & _
    "[Instructor],[DateCompleted],[Completed],[Walkin]) VALUES " & _
    "(@UserName, @SubmitTime, @ClassTime, @ClassDate, @Enrolled, @ClassName, @WaitListed, " & _
    "@Instructor, @DateCompleted, @Completed, @Walkin) "

    'Dim comm As New Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
    Dim comm As New MySqlCommand(sql, conn)

    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", UserName)
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SubmitTime", DateTime.Now.ToString())
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClassTime", "0800")
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClassDate", ClassDate)
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Enrolled", Enrolled)
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClassName", ClassName)
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WaitListed", WaitListed)
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Instructor", Instructor)
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateCompleted", DateCompleted)
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Completed", Completed)
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Walkin", Walkin)

    Dim result As Integer = comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
    conn.Close()
    Return True
End Function
```

The following is the UPDATE error:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you took some code that was meant for SQL Server, and are trying to make it work for MySQL.

However, you can't surround identifier names with square brackets in MySQL. Use back ticks (`` `UserName` ``) or double quotes (`"UserName"`) instead if really needed.

Or better still, if your column names don't have spaces or special characters, as is your case, then just the column names without anything else:

```
... UserName, SubmitTime, ClassTime, ...
```

Comment: That seemed to almost fix it, now getting: Incorrect datetime value: '8/21/2016 7:01:54 PM' for column 'SubmitTime' at row 1

Comment: it didn't like the DateTime format I was getting from the VB var.